# Scrapy Crawler - How do I specify which links to crawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl my website http://www.cseblog.com

My spider is as follows:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ## This is BeautifulSoup4
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from blogscraper.items import BlogArticle ## This is for saving data. Probably insignificant.

class BlogArticleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "blogscraper"
    allowed_domains = ["cseblog.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.cseblog.com/",
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\d+/\d+/*"', ), deny=( ))),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        site = BeautifulSoup(response.body_as_unicode())
        items = []
        item = BlogArticle()
        item['title'] = site.find("h3" , {"class": "post-title" } ).text.strip()
        item['link'] = site.find("h3" , {"class": "post-title" } ).a.attrs['href']
        item['text'] = site.find("div" , {"class": "post-body" } )
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Where do I specify that it needs to crawl all the links of the type
http://www.cseblog.com/{d+}/{d+}/{*}.html and
http://www.cseblog.com/search/{*}
recursively

but save data from 
http://www.cseblog.com/{d+}/{d+}/{*}.html

Comment: I might have been hot on the gun, is Rule and SgmLinkExtractor from Scrapy or BeautifulSoup? Cause it's unclear without the import statements unless you know the modules inside out.

Comment: fixed it Sir. Added the import statements. Please advise now. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a crawler on your own site? If the purpose is to capture the data in a database, presumably you can just run queries in your own database?

Comment: @halfer, for testing purpose maybe.

Comment: @halfer its a test example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create either two rules or one telling scrapy to allow the url of those types. Basically you want the rules list will be something like this

```
rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.cseblog.com/{d+}/{d+}/{*}.html', ), deny=( )),call_back ='parse_save' ),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.cseblog.com/search/{*}', ), deny=( )),,call_back = 'parse_only' ))
```

BTW, you should be using crawl spider and rename parse method name unless you want to override the method from the base class.

Both the link types have different callbacks, in effect, you can decide which processed page data you want to save. Rather than having a single callback, and again doing a check on response.url.